# Swagger - calling a service which returns file does not work properly

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui, enunciate

I am having a problem similar to the ones described [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/374) and [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1196). I have a service which returns a pdf file as attachment with `Content-Disposition` header. This works when I call the endpoint from the browser - file is downloaded. On Swagger UI I get a download link after calling the service with response content type `application/pdf`, however that link downloads an empty pdf file:

[image]

Note that my `swagger.json` is generated by Enunciate (version 2.3.0) and the relevant part looks like this:

```
"responses": {
  "200": {
    "schema": {
    "description": "",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/json_File"
  }, ...
```

I tried adding `"type": "file"` to this, but it didn't fix the problem. What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can document the return type of the response (200) as binary (format) instead:

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: successful operation
      schema:
        type: string
        format: binary
```

According to the spec, "binary" (format) refers to "any sequence of octets
"

Ref: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types

Comment: I tried it, but I am still having the same issue. According to the last comment [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/374) type should be `file`.